# An ItemsControl containing UserControl elements

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, itemscontrol

I'm kind of shooting in the dark on this one and have been looking around but couldn't find much of anything related. Pretty much I am trying to create an ItemsControl on a current Window that I've got, so when the user clicks an "Add Product" button on the window, it will add a UserControl to the screen in a horizontal matter.

For starters I am using an MVVM pattern and I have a PricingViewModel which is my ViewModel for the MAIN window. I have a second view model named ComparisonViewModel, which is the ViewModel for the View of the UserControl that I would like to show everytime the user hits the "Add Product" button on the PricingView. Jumping into my code, I've got a declared ObservableCollection and my AddComparison method. The Collection is instantiated in the constructor of the VM.

```
    public ObservableCollection<ComparisonViewModel> Products { get { return _products; } }

    public void AddComparison()
    {
        var products = IoC.Get<ComparisonViewModel>();
        Products.Add(products);
    }
```

Next, I've got and ItemsControl in the PricingView that binds to that collection in the PricingViewModel:

```
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
```

I run it and after hitting add, it just shows the collection name. How can I actually get it to Pop up with a new Comparison User Control when  the user hits Add Comparison? Thanks a ton for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to set the `ItemTemplate` so the `ItemsControl` knows how to render each item in the collection (by default, it is just displaying the result of calling `.ToString()`).

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:ComparisonViewModel}">
                    <!-- EXAMPLE -->
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="2">
                          <DockPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ComparisonResult}"
                                            DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                            DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                          </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: hmmm. Well DataTemplate doesn't have a TargetType property, also I tried to add it as a <UserControl/> and it still does not render. Any chance you can be a tad more specific?

Comment: @JustinPeterson Sorry, that should be `DataType` instead of `TargetType`

Comment: Darn, ya it still does not want to render.
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Leads:ComparisonViewModel}">
                            <UserControl Width="200" Height="450"/>
                        </DataTemplate>

Comment: @JustinPeterson You actually have to define the UI for displaying a `ComparisonViewModel`. See my edit.

Comment: Well isnt that just grabbing the data from a "Comparison" object? That won't actually show the UserControl itself that I had created. The new UI portion is already created as ComparisonView.I know you can mock up  a new UI insice that right there. I might have to just end up doing that

Comment: @JustinPeterson Okay, you can use `ComparisonView`. Instead of `<UserControl …>` use `<namespace:ComparisonView…>` in the `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 5):

I have found that I needed to tell the ItemsControl two things... First is what type of "thing" the ItemsControl is:

```
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

And the second is how to display the Control:

```
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <c:Widget Margin="5" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The final code looks like:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DynamicItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <c:Widget Margin="5" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

You also need to add a reference to your control namespace in the window declaration stuff:

```
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:IHateEverything.Controls"
```